# Ambiguous type variable error related to n ** 0.5

Tags: haskell

FINAL EDIT:

My final function is:

```hs
isPrime n = n > 1 && n < 4
    || n `mod` 2 /= 0
    && n `mod` 3 /= 0
    && length [x | x <- [5, 11..round (sqrt (fromIntegral n))], n `mod` x == 0 || n `mod` (x + 2) == 0] == 0
```

The issue was that I was trying to treat `n` as both a `Floating` in `sqrt n`, and as an `Integral` in `n mod x`. So I had to do `fromIntegral n` to force n to be treated as an `Integral` and not as a `Floating`.

Also I just screwed up some of my code.

---

So I have two functions:

```
primes = filterPrime [2..]
    where filterPrime (p:xs) = p : filterPrime [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p /= 0]
```

above is straight off of haskell.org, an example being `take 5 primes` results in `[2,3,5,7,11]`

My function `isPrime` is the following:

```
isPrime n = isPrime n = n > 1 && n < 4
    || (n `mod` 2 == 0 || n `mod` 3 == 0)
    && length [x | x <- [5, 11..round (n ** 0.5)], n `mod` x == 0 || n `mod` (x + 2) == 0] == 0
```

However, when I call `isPrime` I get the error:

```
EulerMath.hs:6:33: error:
    * No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `round'
    * In the expression: round (n ** 0.5)
      In the expression: [5, 11 .. round (n ** 0.5)]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [5, 11 .. round (n ** 0.5)]
  |
6 |     && length [x | x <- [5, 11..round (n ** 0.5)], n `mod` x == 0 || n `mod` (x + 2) == 0] == 0
  |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

EulerMath.hs:6:40: error:
    * No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of `**'
    * In the first argument of `round', namely `(n ** 0.5)'
      In the expression: round (n ** 0.5)
      In the expression: [5, 11 .. round (n ** 0.5)]
  |
6 |     && length [x | x <- [5, 11..round (n ** 0.5)], n `mod` x == 0 || n `mod` (x + 2) == 0] == 0
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^

EulerMath.hs:6:45: error:
    * No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from the literal `0.5'
    * In the second argument of `(**)', namely `0.5'
      In the first argument of `round', namely `(n ** 0.5)'
      In the expression: round (n ** 0.5)
  |
6 |     && length [x | x <- [5, 11..round (n ** 0.5)], n `mod` x == 0 || n `mod` (x + 2) == 0] == 0
  |                                             ^^^
```

I don't know how to annotate the `isPrime` function correctly (read: I don't know how to annotate properly at all) so I don't get this error

Comment: To annotate you add a line: `isPrime :: Int -> Bool`.

Comment: There are purely integer algorithms to find the floor of the square root of an integer. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) for example. So you can avoid dealing with floating point numbers entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `n ** 0.5` (or simply written as `sqrt n`) requires `n` to be `Floating`:

```
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

But `mod` requires `n` to be `Integral`:

```
mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

Haskell is a language, where there is no implicit type conversions, so you can't just pass an `Int` to `sqrt`. You can try it in GHCi:

```
x = 4 :: Int
sqrt x -- error
```

To solve that conflict you can use such a function `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` that allows you to convert any `Integral` type to any `Num` type, and all `Floating` types are `Num`, so you will be able to use `n` in `sqrt`:

```
isPrime n = length [x | x <- take (round (sqrt (fromIntegral n))) primes, n `mod` x == 0] == 0
```

Also, we can simplify it a bit with `$` application operator to omit some `()` and `null` function to check whether the list is empty:

```
isPrime n = null [x | x <- take (round $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n) primes, n `mod` x == 0]
```

Try it there: https://repl.it/@Yuri12358/so-primes

Comment: I just edited to be `round (sqrt (fromIntegral n))` thanks to you and n. 'pronouns' m.and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the types of tge involved operators.

```
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

You apply both operators to the same variable `n`. There is no type that satisfies both constraints however, and even if there where, Haskell wouldn't know how to choose one.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. One is to say `fromIntegral n ** 0.5` (or, perhaps better, use `sqrt`). Another one can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965149/integer-square-root-function-in-haskell).

Last but not least you may want to notice that taking √n elements from a list of primes doesn't quite make sense. You want primes that are less than √n. Look at the `takeWhile` function.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I was doing the take primes. I was mixing my primes function with the function from [the 6k + 1 test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode). That was just an oopsie doopsie.

I edited the code to use `sqrt n` and I edited the code to use `round (sqrt n)` and both still result in the error for `Floating Int`.

Comment: You cannot take a square root of an integer. Have you looked at fromIntegral?

Comment: I just edited to be `round (sqrt (fromIntegral n))` thanks to you and Yuri and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much